# Next-auth Receiving 404 after login attempt in deployed Vercel application

Tags: authentication, next.js, vercel, next-auth, callbackurl

Developing a next.js application that uses next-auth for authentication. It is currently setup with GitHub as the only Provider.

In development, the authentication works just fine.

In production, after I click "Sign in with GitHub", I am directed to a 404.

I'm 99% sure this has to do with the callback URL I have setup in my GitHub OAuth app. For dev purposes it is set to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/github. Obviously this is no good for a deployed app, but I don't know what to set it to. I've tried a couple of different URL's with no luck.

Other than the callback URL is there anything else I need to set up in my code to get this working in production?

Answer (score 4):

Other than the callback URL, this is from the docs:

https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example#deploying-to-production

> When deploying your site set the `NEXTAUTH_URL` environment variable to the canonical URL of the website.

> ```sh
> NEXTAUTH_URL=https://example.com
> ```

You should set this as a production environment variable on the Vercel dashboard to link to the URL where Vercel deployed your site.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that this is because you changed your .env.local file to contain your GITHUB_ID value, but did not restart next.js to pick up the new value.

Try stopping your dev sever, and restarting it (with `npm run dev`).

The clue is that the Github authentication URL contains `&client_id=` at the end, with no Github ID token.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and I used `next export` for static HTML export. Without `next export`, just simply to use `next build`, it worked for me on vercel.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same 404 problem, it was due to the changes in Version 4 of NextAuth, I was getting a 404 page when logging in and changing the code in nextauth.js fixed it for me, you could try the following:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GitHubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github'

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GitHubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be late but I faced the similar issue and tried all the solutions. Despite having everything correct the issue was still there and after wasting 2hrs finding every possible solution I came to know my code had a typo in the folder name `/{...nextauth}` containing the authentication file.

The file dir should be exactly `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/{your auth file}`

Please take care of dirs :(